# force to re-check availability of files in utorrent

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I downloaded part of my torrent that are in utorrent with bittorrent to the same folder. bit torrent started to check the file and found the downloaded parts exactly.
Sometimes utorrent started to check the availability of files , Then if utorrent started to recheck the file, it wouldn't to download it again.

so, **How to Do Force Re-Checks availability of files in uTorrent?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop downloading file in uTorrent. Right click on it. Search the entry named "Recalculate hash". That's it.

[image]